# Note taking app with WebDav synchronization

Tags: webdav, owncloud, journal

I am looking for a good self hosted notes taking app (self hosted via WebDav, I use OwnCloud)

Some tools that I have currently ruled out - and the reasons why. Happy to be mistaken:

Laverna looks alright but it doesn't support WebDav, and I didn't find a straight forward way to sync it via, for instance, a "database" file or similar.

Tagspaces can be synced just by syncing folders but saves the tags in the filenames (not sure I can think of any scenario in which that would be acceptable). The PRO version saves the tags in "sidecar" files, but the functionality is marked as beta and the PRO version is more expensive than Evernote - it means paying quite a bit for less functionalities (even though the idea behind tagspaces looks quite unique) and hoping that it works.

OpenNote and PaperWork projects seem not very mature or active either.

I don't seem to find any other good tool out there - whether paid or not.

Thanks

Comment: I myself came to roughly the same conclusion, unfortunately. Strange that no one implemented something as obvious as a decent and working note taking application. I invested a few thoughts about what I really would like to see and actually that goes into the direction of a personal and easy to use markdown based wiki... I had the idea of integrating TiddlyWiki with owncloud, so that owncloud acts as a container and generator for TiddlyWiki files which you can access from everywhere or download and use offline, whilst they still keep the ability to upload their changes to the server.

Comment: this question is out of the scope of SO, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ownCloud with ownCloud Notes (https://github.com/owncloud/notes) in the web, it uses WebDAV for syncing. And it integrates with QOwnNotes (http://www.qownnotes.org/) on the desktop. There also is an iOS and Android app that talks to ownCloud Notes.

Comment: I tried that combination, it is a bit frustrating. QOwnNotes promotes support for different folders - Notes is unable to work with them. QOwnNotes uses markdown syntax - Notes is apparently unable to interpret them and shows notes as plain text. QOwnNotes drop a file based database into the folder (sqlite), the purpose is a bit unclear, really just for the tags? There is an additional API offered for installation, but it stays unclear what purpose that actually serves, since the file base syncing is left to the usual owncloud sync client (_not_ WebDav). So all in all: disappointing.

Comment: ownCloud Notes does support markdown.
Yes, the sqlite database of QOwnNotes is used for tagging.
The QOwnNotesAPI is used for accessing the note version and trashed notes on the ownCloud server.
And you can access your ownCloud files via webdav: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/files.html

Comment: Sure, I read all that too. That is why I tried it. The github documentation and the changelog claim, that the notes app _does_ support markdown, but it does not work for me. I read about the motivation for the additional API (though I do not understand why the usual API does not suffice for that), but I fail to find a way to use that with QOwnNotes. And what good does WebDav do in this case? How does it help in this scenario? I would expect it gets used to syncing / uploading notes, but no! The QOwnNote app relies on the client for that! Why?

Comment: > though I do not understand why the usual API does not suffice for that

- because there is no other API for that

> The QOwnNote app relies on the client for that! Why?

- because many users does not use ownCloud, but sync with something else or nothing at all

Comment: Indeed, you appear to be right, the files_versions app relies on internal ajax calls that should probably not be used by other apps. And indeed the ages old plan to finally move those calls into the official WebDav API has apparently silently died. I stopped following the owncloud development because of such things long ago. Very sad story. But frankly, instead of developing another standalone app (QOwnNotes API) for that stuff, why not do a proper job and finally create the API in core? Anways, thanks for the insight!

Comment: This seems the closest to what I am looking for. However, while trying QOwnNotes I get the following error:

Comment: Connection error message: Error downloading https://xxxxx/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/index.php/apps/qownnotesapi/api/v1/note/app_info?format=json&notes_path=/Notes/ - server replied: Not Found

Comment: @Patrizio Bekerle Sorry I don't seem to be able to edit my comments above. The error I am getting is: There was an error connecting to the ownCloud Server!
You also need to have the QOwnNotesAPI app installed and enabled!

Connection error message: Error downloading https://xxxx/ owncloud/remote.php/webdav/index.php/apps/qownnotesapi/api/v1/note/app_info?format=json&notes_path=/Notes/ - server replied: Not Found. I have QOwnNotesAPI installed and enabled though.

Comment: @Tia: Are you sure you entered the correct server url? It's usually just `https://your-domain`. Can you please post an issue at https://github.com/pbek/QOwnNotes/issues

Comment: Ok @PatrizioBekerle putting http://mydomain/owncloud solved the issue. I assumed I had to put the full WebDav url as shown on owncloud settings../remote.php/webdav/.

Comment: Great it works now, @Tia ;) Feel free to head over to https://gitter.im/qownnotes/lobby if you need more help.